# How to change axis labels in a 3d surface plot using plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly, axis-labels, surface

I have a 2D matrix (11 rows, 20 columns) (avgspeed), where first column is penetration, first row (header) is traffic volume, cells are average speed.

|  | 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1,] | 38.5 | 38.1 | 37.7 | 37.2 |
| [2,] | 38.2 | 37.7 | 37.5 | 36.9 |

Full dataset here: https://laesze-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/borsos_attila_o365_sze_hu/EciUlfLjKY5PiLLJJk6v4xEB9qfpU1FA3WrHRaKc7HPKLA?e=nZYbYa

Using plotly I have this surface plot:
[https://chart-studio.plotly.com/~borsosa/1/#/](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Eborsosa/1/#/)

```
p<- plot_ly(z= ~avgspeed)
p <- p %>% add_surface() %>%
  layout(title = "3D surface plot of average speed",
          legend = list(title = list(text="Average speed")), 
         scene = list(
    xaxis = list(title = "traffic volume [veh/h]"),
    yaxis = list(title = "penetration [%]"),
    zaxis = list(title = "average speed [km/h]")))
```

I have two issues I could not solve:

1. How to change the legend title (from avgspeed to Average speed)
2. I would like to see the traffic volume going from 100 to 2000 (seq(100, 2000, by = 100)) on the xaxis and penetration from 0 to 100 (seq(0, 100, by = 10) on the y axis)

Comment: you should add sample data to help us reproduce your issue. Also, it would be worth including an image to visualise your problem, since it's a chart-related.

Comment: Full dataset has been made available. Graph can be found by clicking on the link.

Comment: for future reference of best practice https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 questions, and 2 answers here...

1. `colorbar=list(title='Example 1')` as in my code below.
2. use `range(c(100,2000))` and `ticks = 100` as in my code below.

sources:

- [plot_ly surface plot axes do not cover full range of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828120/plot-ly-surface-plot-axes-do-not-cover-full-range-of-values)
- [Naming legends of 3D Surface plots in R Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49108645/naming-legends-of-3d-surface-plots-in-r-plotly)

[image]

code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)


data = matrix(data = rnorm(100),nrow = 10,ncol = 10)


p = plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(z = ~data,
            name = 'ZED',
            type = 'surface',
            colorbar=list(title='Example 1'))

p %>% 
  layout(
    scene = list(
      xaxis = list(title = 'xaxis',range = c(0,20)),
      yaxis = list(title = 'yaxis'),
      zaxis = list(title = 'zaxis')
    ),
    margin = list(
        b = 40, 
        l = 60, 
        r = 10, 
        t = 25
      )
  )
```